# Ceasar Cipher by Word Length V.2

Tags: python, python-2.x, caesar-cipher

Here is an updated version of my Caesar Cipher script. I am looking for ways to improve it, make it more succinct, and expand it's features.

I would eventually like to add text import and export features.

Here it is with comments galore!

```
####Collin's Caesar Cipher: A Caesar Cipher by Word Length (V.2)

#To import the lowercase alphabet
import string

#Simple line break function
def line_break(x):
    print "-"*x

#setting up some variables
ans = ""
plainText = ""
cipherText= ""
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

#Welcome User, Explain what script does
line_break(20)
print """
Welcome to Caesar Cipher by Word Length
This script takes words and phrases
and codes them by moving each individual
letter up in the alphabet.
\nThe amount the letters move is dependent
on the length of the word.
\nIf the word is three (3) letters long
then each letter is bumped up by three spaces.
So the word \"cat\" becomes \"fdw\"
\nThis script can encrypt and decrypt messages
based on this rule.
"""
line_break(20)

#Short Pause
print "Press return to continue"
raw_input("> ")

#Set a Function to receive and lowercase user input
def get_user_input(x):
    x = raw_input("> ").lower()
    return x

#Set a Function to ask user what they would like to do
def do_what(y):
    print """
What would you like to do?
Press \"e\" to Encrypt a message
Press \"d\" to Decrypt a message
Press \"q\" to quit
    """
    y = get_user_input(y)
    return y

#Ask user if they would like to Encrypt, Decrypt, or Quit
ans = do_what(ans)

while ans != 'q':
    #If they choose Encrypt:
    if ans == "e":
        #Get users input to decipher
        print "What is the message you would like to encrypt?"
        plainText = get_user_input(plainText)
        #Translate it using Caesar Cipher by Length
        #Sets up a for loop for each word (split by spaces)
        for word in plainText.split():
            #newWord variable to be filled
            newWord= ""
            #Loop for each character in a single word
            for char in word:
                #If the character is in the lowercase alphabet...
                if char in alphabet:
                    #finds the characters position in the alphabet 
                    pos = alphabet.index(char)
                    #Takes that position number and adds the length of the word.
                    #%26 is so that any letter past 'z' goes to the beginning 
                    newPos = ((pos + len(word))%26)
                    #The new position is used in the alphabet to find a new character
                    newChar = alphabet[newPos]
                    #The new character is added to a word
                    newWord += newChar
                else:
                    #This is for any non-alphabetical character (!,."' etc.)
                    newWord += char
            #adds the new word to the output followed by a space (to separate the words)
            cipherText += newWord + " "
        #Print out the Translation
        line_break(20)
        print "%r turns into:\n%r" % (plainText, cipherText)
        line_break(20)
        print "Press return to continue"
        raw_input("> ")
        #initializes output text
        cipherText= ""
        #Ask user if they would like to Encrypt, Decrypt, or Quit
        ans = do_what(ans)

    #If they choose Decrypt:
    elif ans == "d":
        #Get users input to decipher
        print "What is the message you would like to decrypt?"
        plainText = get_user_input(plainText)
        #Translate it using Caesar Cipher
        #Very similar to the code for encrypting
        for word in plainText.split():
            newWord= ""
            for char in word:
                if char in alphabet:
                    pos = alphabet.index(char)
                    #This time it subtracts the length of the word from the position
                    #%26 is so that any word "below 'a'" goes to the end of the alphabet
                    newPos = ((pos - len(word))%26)
                    newChar = alphabet[newPos]
                    newWord += newChar
                else:
                    newWord += char
            cipherText += newWord + " "
        #Print out the Translation
        line_break(20)
        print "%r turns into:\n%r" % (plainText, cipherText)
        line_break(20)
        print "Press return to continue"
        raw_input("> ")
        cipherText= ""
        #Ask user if they would like to Encrypt, Decrypt, or Quit
        ans = do_what(ans)

    #If they choose anything else
    else:
        #Print an error code
        print "Command not recognized"
        #Ask them to try again
        print "Please Try Again"
        #Ask if they would like to Encrypt, Decrypt, or Quit
        ans = do_what(ans)

#If they choose Quit 
if ans == 'q':
    #Say Goodbye
    print "Goodbye"
    #End script
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> #To import the lowercase alphabet
> import string
> # ...
> alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
> ```

The same can be accomplished with

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
```

which also makes the comment unnecessary.

---

> ```
> print """
> ...
> So the word \"cat\" becomes \"fdw\"
> \nThis script can encrypt and decrypt messages
> based on this rule.
> """
> ```

You do not need to escape quotes inside a triple quoted string. And you can write line breaks just as literal linebreaks:

```
print """
...
So the word "cat" becomes "fdw"

This script can encrypt and decrypt messages
based on this rule.
"""
```

---

> ```
> #Set a Function to receive and lowercase user input
> def get_user_input(x):
>     x = raw_input("> ").lower()
>     return x
> ```

You are not using the `x` argument of the function. Just write

```
def get_user_input():
    x = raw_input("> ").lower()
    return x
```

or even

```
def get_user_input():
    return raw_input("> ").lower()
```

---

> ```
> #Set a Function to ask user what they would like to do
> def do_what(y):
>     print """
>     ...
>     """
>     y = get_user_input(y)
>     return y
> ```

Since now `get_user_input` does not take a parameter, `do_what` doesn't need one, either:

```
def do_what():
    print """
    ...
    """
    return get_user_input()
```

---

> ```
> #setting up some variables
> ans = ""
> plainText = ""
> ```

Since `ans` is not required as an argument for `do_what`, it doesn't need to be initialized as an empty string. The same goes for `plainText`.

---

> ```
> while ans != 'q':
>     if ans == "e":
>         # encrypt ...
>         ans = do_what(ans)
>
>     elif ans == "d":
>         # decrypt ...
>         ans = do_what(ans)
>
>     else:
>         # error ...
>         ans = do_what(ans)
> ```

A new value for `ans` is fetched in any case at the end of each iteration of the loop, so you can just write it once *outside* the if-else block.

```
while ans != 'q':
    if ans == "e":
        # encrypt ...

    elif ans == "d":
        # decrypt ...

    else:
        # error ...

    ans = do_what()
```

---

> ```
> ans = do_what()
>
> while ans != "q":
>     # do something
>     ans = do_what()
>
> if ans == 'q':
>     # quit
> ```

You can only exit the loop when `ans` gets `"q"` at some point. So you don't need to check that again after the loop!

I suggest the following overall structure for the control flow, which requires writing `ans = do_what()` only once in the whole script:

```
while True:
    ans = do_what()
    if ans == 'q':
        break

    # do something

# quit
```

---

> ```
> if ans == "e":
>     # encrypt
> elif ans == "d":
>     # decrypt
> else:
>     # error
> ```

Right now, where I put those placeholder comments, there is a lot of code. It would be cool if these blocks of code were contained in functions like `do_encryption`, `do_decryption` and `print_error`, so you could literally write:

```
if ans == "e":
    do_encryption()
elif ans == "d":
    do_decryption()
else:
    print_error()
```

Then it would also be possible to use a dictionary as a lookup table to map the letter to the action to be performed:

```
{'e': do_encryption,
 'd': do_decryption}.get(ans, print_error)()
```

Answer (score 2):

- Functions, please.

  The encrypt and decrypt cases are practically identical. They were in fact copy-pasted. The only difference is that encrypt adds, while decrypt subtracts. You should observe that since these operations happen modulo 26, subtracting `x` is identical to adding `26 - x`. So,

  ```
  def transform(word, operation):
      shift_by = len(word) % len(alphabet)
      if operation == 'd':
          shift_by = len(alphabet) - shift_by
      for char in word:
          ...
          new_pos = (pos + shift_by) % len(alphabet)
  ```
- Magic number 26 should be `len(alphabet)` of course.
- Comments are too many and too trivial:

  ```
  #Ask them to try again
  print "Please Try Again"
  ```

  is just noise.